# wp_editor visual tab in meta box doesn't show content

Tags: wp-editor

If you click on the Text tab, you can see the content, but when you switch back to the Visual tab, it displays nothing. It's not white text on white background either... it just has no content. The functionality works otherwise. I can enter or change content via the Text tab, and that works. But it never shows the content in the Visual tab.

I have disabled all plugins and switched to the 2020 theme, running on Wordpress 5.6 on my local machine, same results. Here's my test code:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'custom_editor_meta_box');
function custom_editor_meta_box () {    
    add_meta_box ( 'custom-editor', 'Custom Editor', 'custom_editor_callback', 'post',);
}

function custom_editor_callback ( $post ) {          
    $content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_editor', true);

    wp_editor ( $content, 'custom_editor', array ( "media_buttons" => true ),);
}

add_action('save_post', 'custom_editor_save_postdata');
function custom_editor_save_postdata ( $post_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['custom_editor_nonce'] ) && isset( $_POST['post'] ) ) {
        if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return;
        } 

        if ( !wp_verify_nonce ( $_POST['custom_editor_nonce'] ) ) {
            return;
        } 

        if( 'post' == $_POST['post'] && !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        } 
    } 

    if ( !empty( $_POST['custom_editor'] ) ) {
        $data = $_POST['custom_editor'];
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_editor', $data);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Updated test code (still same results):

```
function custom_editor_meta_box () {    
    add_meta_box ( 'custom-editor', 'Custom Editor', 'custom_editor_callback', 'post',);
}

function custom_editor_callback ( $post ) {          
    $content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_editor', true);

    wp_editor ( $content, 'custom_editor', array ( "media_buttons" => true ) );
}

add_action('save_post', 'custom_editor_save_postdata');
function custom_editor_save_postdata ( $post_id ) {
    if ( !empty( $_POST['custom_editor'] ) ) {
        $data = $_POST['custom_editor'];
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_editor', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: wp_editor ( $content, 'custom_editor', array ( "media_buttons" => true ),); that comma looks odd at the end, what does the PHP error log say?

Comment: @QStudio A comma at the end of an array doesn't cause any issues that I know of, but I deleted it. Good catch. But no change, and no errors reported.

Comment: if( 'post' == $_POST['post'] && !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) { return; } - so, this reject if it IS a "post" and if the user CANT edit posts ?

Comment: @QStudio another good catch. Updated to !== but still with the same issue. Even if I get rid of all the entire if isset section, it doesn't change anything. Besides, that only applies when the post is saved. It's still never displaying the content in the visual tab. I just integrated this https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2 and tried their wysiwyg field, same results. I'm thinking it's an issue with Wordpress/meta boxes.

Comment: No errors in the JS console?

Comment: @QStudio no sir

Comment: @QStudio Confirmed Wordpress issue: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/52050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be a bug with Wordpress 5.6. See [this thread of comments for the same issue](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/issues/1397) with the CMB2 "developer's toolkit for building metaboxes, custom fields, and forms," which I implemented as an alternative to try (it produced the same results I get with the original code I posted).

Comment: Confirmed Wordpress issue: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/52050

Comment: Good spot, I was at a loss :)

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add in case anyone needs a quick temporary patch before the next WP core release: I found installing the Enable jQuery Migrate Helper plugin solved it for several of my custom meta boxes. Obviously not a long term solution.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know.

Comment: You can also install the Classic Editor plugin to turn off Gutenberg, and then it works just fine also.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround that works for me is, make a 'text' mode default for wp-editor, like

```
// Set wp-editor in the 'Text' mode by default.
add_filter(
    'wp_default_editor',
    function () {
        return 'html';
    }
);
```

When we switch from text to visual, the wp-editor(tinyMCE) works fine, though its not a perfect fix but a quick win over adding a whole new plugin(Enable jQuery Migrate Helper).

Comment: Good news about this issue, soon the fix will be rollout by WP.
The [issue](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/52050) is closed, and on the way to release with [WPv5.8](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/query?status=closed&group=resolution&milestone=5.8) 

As per the [roadmap](https://wordpress.org/about/roadmap/), the WPv5.8 will be released by July 2021.